# Setting local variables inside a function for unit testing kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-testing

I'm trying to testing a function in android.For the function to be tested ,have to set local variable inside the function. Heres the code:

```
 fun needToBeTested(serviceContext: Context):Int
    {
        val manager = serviceContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
        val deviceList = manager.deviceList
        

            if(deviceList.size != 0){
                val deviceIterator = deviceList.values.iterator()
                while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                    val device = deviceIterator.next()
                    
                    if ((device != null)&&(device.deviceClass == 255)) {   // USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC - HUB
                        val permitToRead:Boolean = manager.hasPermission(device)
                        if(permitToRead){
                            setUpConnection(device,serviceContext)
                        } else{
                            manager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
                        }
                        deviceConnectionStatus = 1
                    } else if((device != null) &&(device.deviceClass == 0)){ // USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE - USB STICK
                       
                    }
                }
            } else (deviceList.size == 0){
                connectionStatus = 0
                }
            }
```

**Test class**

class Test {

```
val mockContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()



    @Test
    fun needTobeTested_returnOne(){

    asserThat(sample.needToBeTested(mockContext)==1) //successcase
```

}
}

For testing this class,need to set the value of **deviceList**.Is there any way to set the value of 'x' from the test class for testing this function. Im new to android and testing.Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you give a better example? Your method `needToBeTested` has a variable which it is always 2 - why would ever need to set it in a test?

Comment: You can't mock local variables

Comment: What are you setting the local variable(s) _from_? If it's hard-coded somewhere in the class (as in this example), then it's an implementation detail and shouldn't need to be touched; you just test the function's result.  Otherwise, it's from something external, so that external thing is what you mock or otherwise control.

Comment: @mattfreake ive updated the code..that variable gives the devices connected to the system and since it is a local variable without passing that condition , i cant test the rest of code..

Comment: I don't see any `x` local variable.

Comment: You can mock your `serviceContext` object to return a mock `manager` with a deviceList of size 2 or whatever you want to test. It's a bit fiddly but that's because your function is tightly coupled with `ServiceContext` and `UsbManager` currently. Once you have a working test you can try refactoring your function to make it simpler/less tightly coupled.

Comment: @mattfreake could not find anything to mock Usb manager!!